# Preencher o atributo src de um iframe e torná-lo visível via jQuery quando usuário clicar em item

Tags: html, jquery, iframe

Tenho uma página Web com uma navbar no topo e um iframe que carrega outra página abaixo.

A ideia é que quando o usuário clicar no item do menu via jQuery eu preencha o atributo src do iframe com a página e ele carregue. Mas não esta funcionando.

O código do botão:

```
(....)
<li class="nav-item  dropdown active mx-3">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="menuCadastros" role=button data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Cadastros
    <span class="sr-only">(Página Atual)</span>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menuCadastros">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="cadastrarmorador.php">Morador</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="" id="cadUser">Usuário</a>           
  </div>
</li>
(....)
```

O jQuery é este:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){               
   $('#areaCentral').hide();
   $('#cadUser').click(function(){
      $('iframe').attr('src','cadastrarusuarios.php');
      alert($('iframe').attr('src'));
      $('#areaCentral').show(); 
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar um `event.preventDefault()` no evento do click para impedir que o link redirecione ou recarregue a página. O resto do código me parece normal:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $('#areaCentral').hide();
   $('#cadUser').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $('iframe').attr('src','cadastrarusuarios.php');
      alert($('iframe').attr('src'));
      $('#areaCentral').show(); 
   });
});
```

```css
#areaCentral{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li class="nav-item  dropdown active mx-3">
     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="menuCadastros" role=button data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Cadastros
       <span class="sr-only">(Página Atual)</span>
     </a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menuCadastros">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="cadastrarmorador.php">Morador</a>
       <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="" id="cadUser">Usuário</a>   
     </div>
   </li>
</ul>
<div id="areaCentral">
   iframe aqui
   <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```